# What is the postgreSql equivalent of Oracle timestamp(6). Does postreSql support timestamp in nanoseconds format?

Tags: postgresql, oracle, timestamp

How do I execute the following Query from Oracle in PostgreSql:

```
SELECT to_timestamp('20210603033632200995','yyyymmddhh24missFF6');
```

Comment: `SELECT to_timestamp('20210603033622200','yyyymmddhh24missMS');`  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=4fd4371b0346d0e9e021cce21e724e2f

Comment: SELECT to_timestamp('20210603033632200995','yyyymmddhh24missUS'); Is this replacement right ?

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL has the standard conforming data type `timestamp`.

Six decimal places are microseconds, and yes, PostgreSQL supports that. It does not support nanoseconds, which would be 9 decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

I derived at

`SELECT to_timestamp('20210603033632200995','yyyymmddhh24missUS');`

This worked in PostgresSql workbench. Can anyone else the verify this solution?

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b220060f7029507c29ab1f81c5e0acbd

Comment: @Subarmarekha, PostgresSQL does not support nanoseconds. The real format for Microseconds is MS, which is timestamp(6)